# UIButton Not Rounding Correctly despite corner radius being half the height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uikit

I am working on a screen that essentially allows a user to input some information for their profile. There is a button on this screen that users can use to select their gender. I want to style these buttons to be rounded, so to accomplish this I make the cornerradius of these buttons to be exactly one half of their height. To get to this screen there are two ways, one is if you are creating your profile, and the second is if you are editing your profile. The issue is, when you are creating the profile the UIButton gets pinched and doesn't round correctly, but when I am editing my profile it rounds correctly, even though it is the exact same code, the only difference is that when you are on the screen to edit your profile, I enable the navigation bar.

The code I use to round the button is here:

```
        maleButton.layer.borderColor = maleButtonColor.cgColor
        maleButton.setTitleColor(maleButtonColor, for: .normal)
        maleButton.layer.cornerRadius = maleButton.frame.size.height / 2
```

and this happens in a function that is called in:  `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

The difference in these buttons are shown below:
Note** These are the exact same buttons, only difference is in the second picture the background color has been change to show that the user had selected that button, since they are editing their profile.

[image]

[image]

I printed out the heights, widths, and cornerradius that the buttons:

When it isn't working here are the values:
[image]

And when it is working here are the values:
[image]

As you can see in both cases the corner radius is exactly half the height, so it should be rounding correctly, but it just doesn't. And it is weird because it is the exact same code and same view controller in different situations where it works and doesn't work. This issue has been stumping me, so was hoping someone could help shed some light on it. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, did you try disabling the nav bar when 'creating' profile to see if that changes how the button is curved?

Comment: I did try that, and it still worked in that scenario, but not in the other.

Comment: still worked? I thought creating profile was the situation where it fails?

Comment: No, I think you read the post wrong, as you can see the navigation bar is enabled when they are editing not creating. So what I did was try disabling the bar when editing to see if that would cause the button to pinch, but it didn't.

Comment: can you make the button height to an even number

Comment: Did you added the call to the super after overriding?

Comment: @AdarshKC I dont think this is an issue with even and uneven heights as the rounding seems to be working in different circumstances with the same height.

Comment: Yes I call the super in the function I overrid

Comment: Are you giving aspect ratio constraint or proportional height/width constraint to view or safe area or with any superview?

Comment: The constraint for height and width are based on multipliers to screen size through storyboard constraints.

Comment: Okay i think that is the cause, Can you please try your code in `viewDidAppear:` method? View did appear has always correct frame. If it works i can also give you alternate approaches.

Comment: Ah, so it worked from the viewDidAppear function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Wana_B3_Nerd main reason for this cause is your proportional height. `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` always give height set in storyboard. In `viewDidAppear:` you will always get updated frame. you can resolve this issues in many ways. I am suggesting ways which i knew.

1. Do code in `viewDidAppear:` method
2. If `viewDidAppear:` is not applicable and you wish to do code in `viewDidLoad` then add code in main dispatch queue

   ```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // your code
    }
   ```
3. Subclass UIButton and add your code in `drawRect` method.

   ```
    class RoundButton: UIButton {

        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
             // Your code
         }   

    }
   ```

Comment: I will just do it in viewDidiAppear, is there any drawbacks to doing it in this function?

Answer (score 0):

A clean way without having to care about taking additional steps in your code is by subclassing the button and doing this:

```
            public class CapsuleButton: UIButton {
                
                public override func setNeedsLayout() {
                    super.setNeedsLayout()
                    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height/2
                }

                required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
                    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
                    layer.masksToBounds = true
                }
            }
```

You are likely to be subclassing the UIButton anyway to maintain the look and feel throughout your app.